# BeautifulSoup/Selenium: cannot find div, or any content in the body

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal is to get item names (cotton shirt) and prices (¥3,600) inside `<div class="items-box-body">`

```
<div class="items-box-body">
    <h3 class="items-box-name font-2">cotton shirt</h3>
    <div class="items-box-num">
       <div class="items-box-price font-5">¥3,600</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I used the code below but couldn't access any `div`. When I tested `soup.find_all()`, I couldn't see any contents between `body`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\...', chrome_options=options)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

site_url = 'https://www.mercari.com/jp/search/?sort_order=&keyword=&category_root=1&category_child=11&category_grand_child%5B122%5D=1&brand_name=&brand_id=&size_group=&price_min=&price_max=&item_condition_id%5B1%5D=1&shipping_payer_id%5B2%5D=1&status_on_sale=1'
response = driver.get(site_url)
time.sleep(5)

print(soup.html.unwrap())
>> <html></html>

test = soup.find_all()
print('1',test)
>> [<head></head>, <body></body>]

body = soup.body()
print('2',body)
>> 2 []

for item in soup.select('div[class*="default-container "]'):
    print('3', item)
>>

for item in soup.select('div[class*="items-box-body"]'):
    print('4', item)
>>
```

What did I do wrong?

For the hyperlink: [https://www.mercari.com/jp/search/?...](https://www.mercari.com/jp/search/?sort_order=&keyword=&category_root=1&category_child=11&category_grand_child%5B122%5D=1&brand_name=&brand_id=&size_group=&price_min=&price_max=&item_condition_id%5B1%5D=1&shipping_payer_id%5B2%5D=1&status_on_sale=1)

Comment: Probably because you're trying to obtain a page source before you have loaded the page? Try to use `soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")` after `response = driver.get(site_url)`. Not before..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the product name and price.
Induce `WebDriverWait`() and wait for `visibility_of_all_elements_located`() to load elements and then take the `page_source` for further process.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

site_url = 'https://www.mercari.com/jp/search/?sort_order=&keyword=&category_root=1&category_child=11&category_grand_child%5B122%5D=1&brand_name=&brand_id=&size_group=&price_min=&price_max=&item_condition_id%5B1%5D=1&shipping_payer_id%5B2%5D=1&status_on_sale=1'
driver.get(site_url)
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".items-box")))
html=driver.page_source
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.items-box'):
    print(item.find_next('h3',class_='items-box-name font-2').text.strip())
    print(item.find_next('div', class_='items-box-price font-5').text)
```

---

You can do it without selenium using python requests module.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent':
       'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
res=requests.get("https://www.mercari.com/jp/search/?sort_order=&keyword=&category_root=1&category_child=11&category_grand_child%5B122%5D=1&brand_name=&brand_id=&size_group=&price_min=&price_max=&item_condition_id%5B1%5D=1&shipping_payer_id%5B2%5D=1&status_on_sale=1",headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(res,'html.parser')
for item in soup.select('.items-box'):
    print(item.find_next('h3',class_='items-box-name font-2').text.strip())
    print(item.find_next('div', class_='items-box-price font-5').text)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! May I ask why `time.sleep()` does not work in this case? How `WebDriverWait()` is different from `time.sleep()`?

Comment: @Jan : `WebDriverWait()` wait for the expected condition which is wait for visible of all the elements once visible it will move to next statement Where `time.sleep()` wait up to specific time no matter element is visible or not visible.